# C++ Serial Communication

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 and I seem to be having trouble with termios. 
So I can start minicom open the serial port at 57600 Baud, 8N1, no hardware or software flow control and it works great. I type in @17 5  and my device responds. When I try to set up my serial port in my C++ code I don't get a response. I know that the software is communicating to the port because an led turns on.

Here is my main:

```
int main(void)
{
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

  fd = open("/dev/keyspan1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      /*
       * Could not open the port.
       */

      perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
    }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

  /*****************************CHANGE PORT OPTIONS***************************/
  struct termios options;

  /*
   * Get the current options for the port...
   */

  tcgetattr(fd, &options);

  /*
   * Set the baud rates to 57600...
   */

  cfsetispeed(&options, B57600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B57600);

  /*
   * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
   */

  options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

  /*
   * Set the new options for the port...
   */


  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
  /***********************************END PORT OPTIONS***********************/

  int n;
  n = write(fd, "@17 5 \r", 7);
  if (n < 0)
    fputs("write() of 8 bytes failed!\n", stderr);

  char buff[20];

  sleep(1);

  n = read(fd, buff, 10);

  printf("Returned = %d\n", n);

  close(fd);

  return(0);
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to include a \n at the end of the string you send?

If not that, you can have a look at my RS-232 code that works under Linux:  search for tcsetattr (etc) in this file:  

https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/RS232DataIO.cpp

(Ignore the Windows bits, they aren't relevant to your situation)

Comment: Shouldn't need a `\n`… this is an unbuffered operation on an unbuffered file.

Comment: It all depends on what is listening on the other end of the serial line, and whether it is looking for a \n or not, I would think.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Unbuffered indicates kernel-side handling of the descriptor. The write() function can (and does, at least with glibc) perform user-side buffering, in order to limit the # of syscalls issued. Use fsync() after each block of write() to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to initialize your terminal to raw mode. I suggest you use `cfmakeraw()` to initialize the term options structure. Among others, cfmakeraw will make sure that flow control is disabled, parity checks are disabled, and input is available character by character.

cfmakeraw is non-Posix. If you're concerned with portability, look up the cfmakeraw manpage for the settings it is making.